# Swap Images In a JTable On-Click, via Keyboard

Tags: java, jtable, gridbaglayout

I'm creating a decrypting application that utilizes images placed within a JTable. What I am intending to do with this is, by cliciking a given cell in the table, a text prompt of some kind will come up and request a character from the user. Once the key is pressed, all cells sharing that image will be replaced by another image of the entered key.

It is currently setup with a simple *java.awt.event.MouseEvent* to show the path to the image, but I am at a bit of a loss as to how I can make the actual key prompt appear and accept an input. I have tried a similar action with JButtons, but to no avail. I have also tried brutishly changing the image's path on click, but this too caused error.

Are there any suggestions as to how this may function, and if not, perhaps a different environment that could be used for this application instead?

Comment: [How to use dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)?

Comment: Oh geez, that was staring me right in the face. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to forest, watch out for the trees ;)